# C# template class, where T : ITemplate<any>

Tags: c#, templates, inheritance

I want to do something like:

```
class ClassA<T>: ClassB where T : ITemplatedInterface<Any>
{
}
```

Although I can't do that because "Any" has to be a real type (or template type passed through `ClassA<>`.

For example, `T` can be a class that inherits `ITemplatedInterface<SomeConcreteType>`, but I don't want to specify the concrete type within `ClassA`, I just want to ensure that `T` inherits from `ITemplatedInterface`.

I know this could be solved by passing the `SomeConcreteType` as the second template type in `ClassA<T, SecondT>`, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: Do you really need a `ITemplatedInterface` generic in this case?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes, because it exists and is used apart from this class

Comment: Can you make ITemplatedInterface<T> inherit from a new non-generic interface: ITemplatedInterface and have the T constraint for classA bound to that instead?

Comment: @NikolaDim Can you share minimal reproducible sample? And sources of `ITemplatedInterface<T>` and `ClassA<>`, because it's not clear, what is the problem with this declaration `class ClassA<T> : ClassB where T : ITemplatedInterface<SomeConcreteType>` You can avoid specifying the concrete type by making `ITemplatedInterface` non generic

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the problem with ```<SomeConcreteType>```is that then ```ClassA``` only works with that type. I was curious on is it possible to use a type ```T``` which inherits from a templated interface without specifying the concrete type. Maybe that ability is uncalled for (or signals a code smell), but I wanted to know if it was doable without restructuring the code. Thanks!

Comment: You named all your options alread in your Question. it's either `class A<T, Any>` or `ITemplatedinterface<concreteType>`. Nothing else is possible. "Any" cannot not fall from heaven.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use casting and manipulate it accordingly? Something like:

```
using Linq;

class ClassA<T>: ClassB where T : () x=> (typeOf(...) ITemplatedInterface<Any>) 
    {
    ...
    }
```

or

```
class ClassA<T>: ClassB where T : ITemplatedInterface<Any> () <= (typeOf(...) 
    {
    }
```

I will try it later to prove it, as this is time consuming, but interesting to find out.

Comment: It’d be preferable to wait until you’ve found out to post this, instead of posting a speculative answer.